# How to get the average without using the sum function

Tags: python

Heres my code below

```
def average(a_list):  # returns average value of a list of numbers.
    total = 0
    a_list = []
    for n in (a_list):
        total += n
    return total/ len(a_list)
```

But I keep getting an error that my "len(a_list)" doesn't work because it is dividing by zero

Comment: remove  `a_list = []` and optionally also remove the parentheses on `for n in (a_list):`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this function? Looks like you are making your own version of len() and then trying to compare that result with len()'s result, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's zero: you very specifically destroyed your input argument just before you entered the loop.  Don't ***do*** that!

Remove that statement:

```
def average(a_list):  # returns average value of a list of numbers.
    total = 0
    for n in a_list:
        total += n
    return total / len(a_list)
```

Comment: Oh you're the best! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not really ... I'm just old enough that I've made a lot of mistakes.
Now I recognize them, and have to find new ones ...

Comment: well thank you for the insight, you're greatly appreciated